# What does “shooting trout in a demitasse cup” mean?

Tags: phrases

I came across the phrase, “shooting trout in a demitasse cup” in the New York Times’ columnist, Maureen Dawd’s article titled *[Coffee Cups in Hell](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/27/opinion/27dowd.html?hp)*. Incidentally, I as a non-native English speaker often feel her writing style studded with novel and cool phrases difficult to comprehend.

Though I guess this phrase means ‘100% certain' (Please correct me if I wrong), is this an established expression? I wonder if she deliberately used this phrase in association with Mormons’ shunning caffeine.

The phrase is used in the following context:

> They (Trey Parker, Matt Stone, Robert Lopez) pushed the limits at Comedy Central when they put the Prophet Muhammad in a bear suit. But as Terry Teachout wrote in The Wall Street Journal: “Making fun of Mormons in front of a Broadway crowd is like “shooting trout in a demitasse cup.” ... If the title of this show were ‘The Quran,’ it wouldn’t have opened.

Comment: From this and other questions, I feel I should point out that native English speakers often find Maureen Dowd's writing studded with strange phrases difficult to comprehend (and often not worth the effort),

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It comes from *[“shooting fish in a barrel”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_fish_in_a_barrel)*, which means “extremely easy”, as it is supposedly hard to miss a target in this restricted space. So, your expression is not an established idiom, but is built from this rather common phrase by replacing the barrel with the much smaller *demitasse* (which is a small coffee cup). So it is built to mean “even easier than shooting fish in a barrel”, with an added *coffee* connotation as you noted in your question.

<sup>As an aside, the [Mythbusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters) have tested and validated the easiness of [shooting fish in a a barrel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pd-MpXCMcIs). As another aside, French has a related idiom to mean “miss something trivial” which is “to miss an elephant in a corridor”.</sup>

Comment: I really enjoyed watching youtube footage for outrageous demonstration of easiness to shoot a fish in barrel. I almost split my sides with laughter.

Comment: @Yoichi This -- taking an established idiom or saying and constructing variations -- is used quite often in English.  I like to refer to "with a grain of salt" (the well-known phrase), and its malleability: depending on how doubtful a mention bit of data is, you can recommend "a spoonful of salt" all up to "a sixty-car freight train full of salt". Or any other imaginative measurement.